# Edit page blank, control buttons missing

Tags: visual-editor, post-editor

Lately I encountered a strange problem while editing posts and pages.

I have  a blank page with all controls missing (like publish etc.).

I tried to deactivate all plugins. I tried to upgrade wordpress to newest version. But still, no effect.

Does enyone encountered similar problem? How can I fix this?

[image]